# Changing styles of fontawesome icons

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9

I am using font awesome icons in my angular code. My code is as follows:

```
component.ts:
import { faSquare } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

 faSquare =faSquare;

html:

<fa-icon [icon]="faSquare"</fa-icon>
```

I want to change width, height and rotate this square by 45 degree. I tried giving styles using inline styling but it is not working. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide inline styles to the icon as:

```html
    <fa-icon [icon]="faSquare" [styles]="{height: '30px', width: '30px', transform: 'rotate(45deg)'}"></fa-icon>
```

Output:

[image]

You can also refer the [Features](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/5e897dc284dec645251c46ae27617cb5d5b2a6d7/docs/usage/features.md#fixed-width) documentation to explore more.